# T-SQL Insert null if ' ' input is empty

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

My web-application allows for token replacements and therefore my SQL INSERT query looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('[Col1Value]', '[Col2Value]', '[Col3Value]')
```

The web app is replacing whats inside the brackets `[Col1Value]` with the input entered into the form field.

Problem is when an input field is left empty this query is still inserting `' '` just an empty space so the field is not considered `null`

I'm trying to use SQL's default value/binding section so that all columns that are `null` have a default value of `--` but having my query insert a blank space `' '` is making it so SQL does not trigger the default value action and it still shows blank rather than my desired default value of `--`

Any ideas as to how I can solve this and make sure `' '` is inserted as a `null` rather than a space or empty space so it will trigger SQL replacing null with my default value of `--`

Comment: Note that explicitly inserting NULL won't allow SQL to apply the default value either.  You actually have to not include the column in both the column list and the value list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy going...

How are you inserting the values? If you create these statements literally you are stumbling on the dangerous fields of **SQL injection**... Use parameters!

One approach might be an insert through a *Stored Procedure*, another approach is an *Instead Of TRIGGER* and the third uses the fact, that the *string-length* does not calculate trailing blanks:

```
SELECT LEN('')   --returns 0
      ,LEN('  ') --returns 0 too
```

You can use this in an expression like this:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(@YourInputValue)=0 THEN NULL ELSE @YourInputValue END
```

Comment: I am inserting values using a T-SQL query that is inputted into the web-application as the values are inputted by a user on my form on the website. I'll review the `CASE WHEN LEN` approach and see if I can accomplish the desired result.

Thank you for your time.